# Can I somehow use the endpoint override django.settings

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, settings

In the settings, I have several variables, these are strings. Can I somehow rewrite them with the help of some endpoint in jango?
My thanks!

Comment: You should never do this. Think of settings as static. The biggest issue is that once you have more and more app servers your simple settings change will be limited to the app server that received this request... its VERY frowned upon. Look at keeping your dynamic settings in postgres/redis/zookeeper/...

Comment: Shoot! https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance